# problems with relative time function in php

Tags: php

I have used many functions for relative time in php but that give different results...help me

My functions :

```
<?php 
function pretty_relative_time($time) { 
  if ($time !== intval($time)) { $time = strtotime($time); } 
  $d = time() - $time; 
  if ($time < strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')) - 60*60*24*3) { 
    $format = 'F j'; 
    if (date('Y') !== date('Y', $time)) { 
      $format .= ", Y"; 
    } 
       return date($format, $time); 
} 
if ($d >= 60*60*24) { 
  $day = 'Yesterday'; 
  if (date('l', time() - 60*60*24) !== date('l', $time)) { $day = date('l', $time); } 
  return $day . " at " . date('g:ia', $time); 
} 
if ($d >= 60*60*2) { return intval($d / (60*60)) . " hours ago"; } 
if ($d >= 60*60)   { return "about an hour ago"; } 
if ($d >= 60*2)    { return intval($d / 60) . " minutes ago"; } 
if ($d >= 60)      { return "about a minute ago"; } 
if ($d >= 2)       { return intval($d) . " seconds ago"; } 
else    {return "Just Now"; }

}
function plural($num) {
if ($num != 1)
    return "s";
 }

   function getRelativeTime($date) {
$diff = time() - strtotime($date);
if ($diff<60)
    return $diff . " second" . plural($diff) . " ago";
$diff = round($diff/60);
if ($diff<60)
    return $diff . " minute" . plural($diff) . " ago";
$diff = round($diff/60);
if ($diff<24)
    return $diff . " hour" . plural($diff) . " ago";
$diff = round($diff/24);
if ($diff<7)
    return $diff . " day" . plural($diff) . " ago";
$diff = round($diff/7);
if ($diff<4)
    return $diff . " week" . plural($diff) . " ago";
return "on " . date("F j, Y", strtotime($date));
 }


 echo pretty_relative_time('2012-08-06 8:04:15') ;echo "<br/>";
 echo getRelativeTime('2012-08-06 8:04:15');
 ?>
```

OutPut :

Just Now   // for first function

-15747 seconds ago // for second function

any settings in db ?.....i have used DATETIME for date...

Comment: change $diff = time() - strtotime($date); TO-> $diff = time() - $date;

Comment: than it give "on August 6, 2012" not 1 hour ago .....:(

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made clear what output you're expecting, but from your later comment it should be "1 hour ago"? In which case I suspect you are suffering from timezone problems - most likely the dreaded "Daylight Savings Time". Try echoing `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` in PHP and seeing if it comes out with the value you expect.

The discrepancy could be in the timezone set in php.ini, or the system clock of the webserver itself, not matching the timezone setting of the database, or the system clock on that server.

Comment: ok echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') output : 2012-08-06 04:17:41  and current in colck time is 9:45 AM

Comment: Right, so your sample input is (according to the server's notion of "now") 4 hours in the future, whereas the pretty-printing functions you're using expect it to be in the past.

That timestamp corresponds to current UTC/GMT time, whereas your database is presumably returning your local time. I would recommend getting your database to return UTC (you didn't tell us what DB you're using and how, so I can't be more specific)

Comment: OK. I'm not expert enough on MySQL to advise further, unfortunately.

Comment: $m=date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); echo $m; echo pretty_relative_time($m); Not working

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? I would expect that code to always echo "Just Now", since it is always passing the current time into the pretty-print function. Is that not the result you get?

Comment: To make sure this is clear: date('Y-m-d H:i:s') is just a way of displaying what time your PHP script thinks is "now". Your database has a different idea of "now", and that is causing your problem. You can do one of 3 things: change the timezone of your DB to UTC; change the timezone of your PHP script to match your database; or adjust the values you are pulling out. I would recommend the first option, as UTC gives you a consistent base regardless of DST, moving to a different timezone, etc